# Getting json data for dropdown list using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Looking for information on how to read a json from an api call we have to populate a dropdown list.

```
[
   {
       "name": "jira",
       "description": "The default JIRA workflow."
   },
  {
       "name": "Business Review and Build",
       "description": "The default JIRA workflow starting point."
  }
]
```

The json does not seem to have opening and closing { .. }.  It looks basically like what I pasted in above.  I guess it is like an anonymous array of two values, name, and description. It is retrieved via a url that has a go script running that outputs this json.

I tried to use jquery, but something like this does not display any options.

```
function populateWF() {
    let dropdown = $('#projWF');
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose a workflow');
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    const url = 'http://esjira01d.internal.company.com:8088/workflows';

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $.getJSON(url, function(obj) {
         $(obj).each(function() {
             dropdown.append($('<option>/option>')
             .val(this.Name).html(this.Description));
        }); #each
      }); #getJSON
   }); #ready
}
```

The option box does dispaly and it does say the mesage about Choose a workflow.  It just seems to bomb at the actual getJSON.

It does not display anything in the drop down.  If I go to the url, it shows what appears to be json. If I go to jlint and type in what I think it is returning, it says it is valid.

Comment: just use a normal for loop or foreach...

Comment: It seems to work if I use json data with  { "wf": at the top and a closing parenthesis at the bottom, but he go api is not delivering it in that manner.  It has no open/close parenthesis with a name (e.g., "wf").  I am not sure how to modify the getJSON and each loop to work without those things.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. JSON does not need `{}` at the start and end

Comment: I see now from your comments that this is not an object.  Those are some great ways to address.  It is kind of interesting to wonder whether there is a point to use map or not or just do the forEach.  Is one way more efficient than another I wonder.

Comment: Map makes no sense here

Comment: @Luca What do you mean by makes no sense? Regardless the fact we may or may not need to change anything in the array. Map is still a valid option here and it might gives a better performance. https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f

Comment: I am not sure it is even hitting the url.  If I run something like curl:  curl http://esjira01d.unx.sas.com:8088/workflows | jq '.'  it displays the json.  Also, you see at the listener it shows that it was queried.  It does not appear the getJSON is hitting the server.

Comment: curl -X GET -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" http://esjira01d.unx.sas.com:8088/workflows  This returns json, but getJSON call is not seen.

Answer (score 2):

The data you get back is a normal Array of Objects encoded as JSON. To get the values, you can use a simple for-loop or the `.forEach()` function:

```js
let obj = '[{"name":"jira","description":"The default JIRA workflow."},{"name":"Business Review and Build","description":"The default JIRA workflow starting point."}]';

obj = JSON.parse(obj);

let dropdown = $("#dropdown");

obj.forEach(function(e) {
  let option = $('<option></option>');
  option.val(e.name);
  option.html(e.description);
  dropdown.append(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown"></select>
```

```
function populateWF() {
    let dropdown = $('#projWF');
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose a workflow');
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    const url = 'http://esjira01d.internal.company.com:8088/workflows';

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $.getJSON(url, function(obj) {
        obj.forEach(function(e) {
          let option = $('<option></option>');
          option.val(e.name);
          option.html(e.description);
          dropdown.append(option);
        });
      }); 
   }); 
}
```

Comment: This would have been cool with easy adjustment to existing code, but it did not populate the dropdown for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The result you received is an array instead of object. You can use `.map()` function to create the options.

```js
var result = [
   {
       "name": "jira",
       "description": "The default JIRA workflow."
   },
  {
       "name": "Business Review and Build",
       "description": "The default JIRA workflow starting point."
  }
]

 $(document).ready(function() {
     
     result.map(function(item) {
         $("select").append($('<option></option>').val(item.name).html(item.description));
     }); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```